# Column Space, Rank and Matrix Concatenation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

I have the following question:

Given Matrices $A$ and $B$, the following relation exists between their column spaces:

$$\text{col}(B) \subseteq \text{col}(A)$$

Then, which of the following is true for Matrix $C=[A\,\,\,\,\,B]$?

**A)** $\text{rank}(C)=\text{rank}(A)$

**B)** $\text{rank}(C)=\text{rank}(B)$

**C)** It is not possible to specify $\text{rank}(C)$ in terms of $\text{rank}(A)$ and $\text{rank}(B)$

My guess, and it seems a reasonable one, would be alternative **(A)**, but I don't know how to solve/express it mathematically.

Is my guess correct? Could you walk me through the steps to prove it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is true that $\mathrm{rank}(C) = \mathrm{rank}(A)$, since $\mathrm{col}(C)\subset\mathrm{col}(A)$ and vice versa.

Comment: What is the column space of C?

Comment: $C \binom{x}{y} = Ax + By$. Hence ${\cal R}C = {\cal R}A + {\cal R} B$. You are given ${\cal R}B \subset {\cal R} A$.

Comment: Is it correct that if $\text{col}(B) \subseteq \text{col}(A)$, then $\text{rank}(B) \leq \text{rank}(A)$ and the rank of a concatenated matrix is equal to the maximum rank among the concatenating matrices? Is this a way to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's correct.

The columns of $C$ are just the columns of $A$ followed by the columns of $B$, which are all included in $\mathrm{col}(A)$, hence
$$\mathrm{col}(C) \ =\ \mathrm{col}(A)$$
so their dimensions - the ranks - coincide.